# DDR3 ram not working

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, uefi, memtest

I have bought a 4 GB DDR3 memory RAM stick which should be compatible with my motherboard and, for the third time, I cannot make it work. The first time the memory test crashed when checking the RAM and the shop confirmed it was broken. The new one I bought didn't work either, so I thought maybe they were sending me the same unit and I returned it.

Now, after some years, I have bought a new memory from another company because I definitely need more RAM to make my computer useful. However, it is also crashing, so I am guessing it may be a BIOS configuration or something else that I am missing, three bad units seems too much bad luck.

This is the info:

- My motherboard is Asus P7H55-M.
- The memory I have bought now is [Corsair Value Select DDR3 1333 PC-10600 4GB CL9](https://www.corsair.com/en/us/Categor%C3%ADas/Productos/Memoria/Memoria-de-consumo-general/CORSAIR-Memory-%E2%80%94-4GB-DDR3-Memory/p/CMV4GX3M1A1333C9#tab-tech-specs)
- I am trying to turn the computer on both with only this stick and together with my previously installed two sticks.
- The memory that I am using up to now without problems are 2x 2GB Kingston KVR1333D3N9/2G (DDR3) adding a total of 4 GB.
- The newly bought memory seems to have same frequency, lag... as the ones I am using.

What can be wrong? Everything in BIOS seems to be to default values (I have changed configuration to restore the defaults).

The only test I haven't done this time is memtest, because I seems that Memtest86 and Memtest86+ are not working because my old motherboard doesn't support UEFI.
#ADDITIONAL INFORMATION 1:
Additional information, from the motherboard manual:

[image: Compatible memories according to motherboard user manual]

#ADDITIONAL INFORMATION 2:
This is my current system with the old 2x 2GB sticks:

[image: Actual system according to CPU-Z]

Comment: Does it also crash if you remove the old memory and only run the new memory? It is possible that both memory sticks are incompatible with eachother. Also, if you have 2x2 GB RAM, you should install another 2x2GB ram, not 1x4GB ram. 2x4GB ram in addition is better, but not optimal

Comment: Are you using the same slots for testing, or different ones?

Comment: The most likely reason the Corsair module does not work is due to you attempting to use it with 2 GB modules.  You don't indicate which slots you are using.  You would have to provide the English manual for any diagnostic of this problem.  The 2 GB modules would have to be in the same channel, they are most likely, in separate channels (as that is the typical rule of thumb).  So when you installed the 4 GB you placed it in a channel that had a 2 GB module.

Comment: I have tested the new memory ALONE, and also together with the previous 2 sticks, without success. Before thinking how to connect the new 4 GB memory together with the previous 2x 2 GB memories, I am trying to make the new one ALONE work, which I can't.

Comment: Which slot exactly did you install the new modules in?

Comment: It is only one new module, and when installed alone, I thought it didn't care where. I don't remember in which ones I have tried (I have tried more than one) but sure I have tried in one of the slots where the old memory sticks work. I made sure that it is not a problem with the connection.

Comment: If there is a way to run memtest or memtest86+ on an old motherboard (perhaps an older version still downloadable somewhere?) please let me know, if you believe that the module can be unbelievably broken.

Comment: I am finally returning the memory stick but don't know what memory I can buy that will work.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is the fact that your ram is diffrent from your motherboard. Yes it is compatible yet corsair probably doesent accept compatibility from asus. If i were you i would get a ram extension from another company.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Asus motherboards do a check on the RAM module to see if it is from a competitor? I’ve never heard of that and it would not be a sound business strategy.

Comment: This answer doesn't have enough information. If the RAM is not compatible it should be because some of its characteristics (which one?), not because the manufacturer.

Comment: If it's compatible shouldn't it work? ASUS does not actually manufacture memory modules, they outsource that compatible to one of the major companies like Corsair or Crucial, and then put their name on it.  Often times ASUS modules are identical to that of the actual manufacture's module.  This answer is also **factually wrong**, DDR3 is a specification, the only way the module would not work is if it's actually low voltage DDR3 module or is an ECC DDR3 module.  There is a saying I typically say, DDR3 is DDR3, same frequency same voltage a given module will be identical no matter who made it.